# POP3 stop mail deletion

Tags: python, email, pop3

I am currently writing an email monitoring script which has to be in POP3.  To test it I am sending dummy mails to a gmail account, but the script will not be used on a gmail client.

I retrieve all messages by:

```
mail = poplib.POP3_SSL("pop.gmail.com", 995)
...
messages = [mail.retr(i) for i in range(1, mail.stat()[0] + 1)]
```

and then export them into a text file.
The problem with this is that whenever I retrieve all my mails, they all get completely wiped off the server (the mails are not even in trash).  At the end of the script I have:

```
mail.rset()
mail.quit()
```

From reading [POP3 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html) and other google searches I believe that it should stop mails being deleted.

What am I missing?

Comment: Always tag with the programming language you're using.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.  I decided to answer my question instead of deleting it because I figured someone might have the same problem.

There is a setting in Gmail under the 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP' tab "mark Gmail's copy as read", that solves the issue.  Subsequent retrievals read only the unread messages, which makes it very easy to append a document with only new information.